# Conversion from hexadecimal string to Double yields wrong results

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I am trying to convert 14 bit hex numbers to decimal.

I have this VBA code.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function HexadecimalToDecimal(HexValue As String) As Double

Dim ModifiedHexValue As String
ModifiedHexValue = Replace(HexValue, "0x", "&H")

HexadecimalToDecimal = CDec(ModifiedHexValue)
End Function
```

With numbers like this to convert to decimal

- 0x047B1142591E80
- 0x044A81325A1E80
- 0x047B7542591E80

I keep getting random results across large amounts of data. Sometimes spot on other times the numbers are off by 6 or 2.

Comment: Kindly provide us with some examples of these erroneous conversions.

Comment: 047B1142591E80 = 1261213964639870 (2 Out)

Comment: 044A81325A1E80 = 1207818662846080 (spot on)

Comment: 047B7542591E80 = 1261643461369470 (2 Out)

Comment: The only thing that's "2 out" are your comments.  Using CDec() to get a Double doesn't otherwise make much sense.

Comment: What would you suggest? In my comments I am showing that the output is wrong for example it should be 1261213964639872 not 1261213964639870 meaning it is 2 out.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the return type of the function from `Double` to `Variant`.  `Double` has only about 15 decimal digits of precision, so can't, for example, capture the value 1261213964639872 (which has 16 digits) exactly.  The closest it can get is 1261213964639870.  By changing the return type to `Variant`, the full precision returned by `CDec` will be preserved.  You can't use a `Decimal` return type, because VBA for some reason does not support this.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but it works for me.  I copied the code from your question, changed `As Double` to `As Variant`, and get `1261213964639872` as the value of the expression `HexadecimalToDecimal("0x047B1142591E80")`.  I'm on Excel 2010 32-bit.

Comment: That change will work in the VBE, but not in the cells themselves. Limitation of Excel that will only display first 15 numbers of a longer number.

Comment: Very strange as it didn't work for me? Excel 2013 64bit

Comment: How did you check the return value?  As @guitarthrower pointed out, if you checked it using a formula on a worksheet, you won't get a precise answer because the worksheet will convert the result to a `Double`.

Comment: I only checked in the excel sheet. Can I force the cells to use the Variant return type?

Comment: If you want to see the precise answer on a worksheet, the only solution is to use `String` (not `Variant`) instead of `Double`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with VBA. Excel cells can only hold 15 digits in number format. So the "number" **`1234567891234567`** will always display **`1234567891234560`**. This can be avoided by converting items to text AND/OR changing the cell format to text.

But this doesn't always work.

The only surefire way to make sure it will retain all digits is to append something onto the string that isn't a number.

This code will append an apostrophe before the number, but return the entire string.

```
Public Function HexadecimalToDecimal(HexValue As String) As String

    Dim ModifiedHexValue As String
    ModifiedHexValue = Replace(HexValue, "0x", "&H")

    HexadecimalToDecimal = "'" & CDec(ModifiedHexValue)
End Function
```

Unfortunately, not a perfect solution.

Comment: Thanks for this, I then created a formula to remove ' and have the final number displayed.